# Perl regex - How to make it less greedy?

Tags: regex, perl

How do I count the number of empty 'fields' in the following string ?
Empty fields are indicated by `-|` or `|-|` or `|-`
The regex I have cooked up seems to be working except when I have consecutive empty fields ? How do I make it less greedy ?

```
my $string = 'P|CHNA|string-string|-|-|25.75|-|2562000|-0.06';
my $count = () = ($string=~/(?:^-\||\|-$|\|-\|)/g);   
printf("$count\n");
```

The above code prints 2 instead of 3 which I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use lookarounds. Someone's first attempt might be the following:

```
my $count = () = $string =~ /
   (?<\|)  # Preceded by "|"
   (-)
   (?=\|)  # Followed by "|"
/xg;
```

But that doesn't work. The problem with the above is that it doesn't detect if the first field or last field is empty. Two ways to fix that:

```
my $count = () = "|$string|" =~ /
   (?<\|)  # Preceded by "|"
   (-)
   (?=\|)  # Followed by "|"
/xg;
```

or

```
my $count = () = $string =~ /
   (?<![^|])  # Not preceded by a char other than "|"
   (-)
   (?![^|])   # Not followed by a char other than "|"
/xg;
```

Comment: Fixed. (Missing `/g`, `=~` instead of `=`)

Comment: Nope.  This will fail for empty fields at the beginning or end of the string (`[^|]` still has to match something, NOT including beginning/end of line markers).

Comment: @EthanBrown `[^|]` failing to match meens that `(?<![^|])` succeeds in matching, which is exactly what we want.

Comment: @Ethan Brown, you are mistaken. Please test before telling someone their code doesn't work.

Comment: Added more comments and explanation.

Comment: Fair enough, @ikegami; you are correct.  My apologies for my hasty comment.  I still think splitting is the smart way to go for this problem, but your solution does work.

Comment: @Ethan Brown, yeah, splitting is definitely more readable, but it's good to know how to do it nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

I'd avoid the regex route entirely for this and instead treat this like a list, because it is one:

```
my $count = grep { /^-$/ } split /\|/, $string;
```

Comment: I agree. I was looking for a regex solution though.

Answer (score 3):

The problem actually doesn't have anything to do with greediness/lazyness (which only applies to repetition operators like `*` or `+`).

The problem is the two empty fields right next to each other: `|-|-|`.  The first one is being matched, but then the second one fails because the opening `|` has already been consumed, but because you have the beining-of-line marker in the rule `^-|`, it doesn't match that one.

I think a much easier approach would be to split your input on `|` and then look for any fields consisting of only a `-`:

```
my $count = 0;
foreach (split(/\|/,$string)) { if( /^-$/ ) { $count++; } }
```

There's really no way to robustly implement this with a regex since Perl doesn't support variable-length lookbehinds (at least not to my knowledge).  One way to "cheat" would be to append a `|` at the beginning and end, then you could successfully use lookbehind/lookahead assertions:

```
$string = "|$string|";
my $count = () = $string=~/(?<=\|)-(?=\|)/g;
```

(ikegama's answer below has an alternative solution that does use non-variable lookaround assertions without modifying the string, so I was wrong when I said there was "no way to implement this with a regex".  Props to ikegama.  I still think splitting on `|` is the best way to go for this problem, though.)

Comment: It can even be down without negative lookarounds: `/(?:^|\|)\K-(?=\z|\|)/`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @ikegami; the `\K` metacharacter is new to me.  I don't do much PCRE these days.  It sure would be nice if all languages could standardize on a regex grammar!  Not that that's ever going to happen.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Perl regexes.  PCRE, supposedly, stays in sync with Perl regexes.  I just think it's unfortunate that there can't be a common superset.  Both Perl and .NET regexes have features that I really envy, and JavaScript lacks some features that I really want.  Oh well.

Comment: What does .NET have that Perl doesn't? (Honest question)

Comment: Perhaps some of these things have been added in Perl; I haven't been keeping up with Perl in the last few years.  But .NET has balanced groups, alternation constructs, and last group substitution.  It's also got named sub-expressions, but I don't ever foresee using that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Comment: It's got recursion for balanced group since 5.10 (much simpler and more flexible solution than balanced groups from the looks of it). It's got (?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern) since 5.8. It's got named sub-expressions since 5.10. Don't know what you mean by "last group substitution".

Comment: I thought greedy matching meant consuming the matched pattern.

Comment: Greedy matching (aka maximal matching) means that a repetition operator (`*`, `+`, `?`, numbered matches) will match as much as possible.  For this to make sense in any way, the repetition is necessary.